# Force ipv4 server identification using DNS64

Tags: domain-name-system, direct-access

I have a requirement that my direct access client should always get the IPv4 address of the server (Server will always have an IPv4 address). 
I know that, DNS64 sends two DNS queries to the corporate DNS server ; 1 for IPv6 and 1 for IPv4 and if it gets a response for IPv6, it will prefer that to send the response back to the client. 
In my case, the server may or may not have an IPv6 address. I would like to have below configuration:

- DNS64 sends DNS queries only for IPv4 address.
- Avoid NAT64 to nat the IPv4 address to IPv6 address. I would like to get IPV4 address only OR IPv4 mapped IPv6 address. I do have specific needs for this which I cannot share here. :(

Are there any ways to achieve above configuration ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To force dns64 to return Only IPv4 record, `exclude { any ; } ;`

Example:

```
:dns64 64:ff9b::/96 {
    clients { 2001:db8:cafe:1::/64; };
    exclude { any; };
};
```